# Reducing the size of a short-content column in a Primefaces Datatable

Tags: html, css, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 6.2.17 and I have a dataTable with basically two types of columns:

- Columns that contain very short texts
- Columns that can contain texts of variable length that can be short or long

For the columns with short texts, I want to specify a fixed sized. For the other columns, I want them to take up the remaining space, using as much space as each individual column requires to fully display its content (if possible) or the space needed to display its column-header. However, the width of the table should never exceed the width of the page.

This is my current implementation:

```
<p:dataTable id="myTab" widgetVar="myTab"
                     var="document"
                     tableStyle="table-layout: fixed; white-space: nowrap; width: 100%;"
                     .....
                     >

  <p:column headerText="Date" width="6%" style="text-align: center">
                    <h:outputText value="#{document.Date}"/>
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Name">
                    <h:outputText value="#{document.name}"/>
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Categorie">
                    <h:outputText value="#{document.categorie}"/>
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Comment">
                    <h:outputText value="#{document.comment}"/>
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Author" width="5%" style="text-align: center">
                    <h:outputText value="#{document.author}"/>
  </p:column>
  
  ...

</p:dataTable>
```

As you can see I use the `width` attribute of `p:column` to set the size for columns with fixed size for those columns with short texts. I set nothing for the other columns of variable lenght. This current implementation makes it so that the remaining space (for columns of non-fixed size) is equally distributed between the remaining columns, regardless of the size of their content:

[image]

I want to change this so that the columns are only as wide as they need to be to display or their content, like this :

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

`components.css` of PrimeFaces has `table-layout: fixed`, you explicitly specifying same through `tableStyle` attribute, so table is rendering with fixed widths. Change `table-layout` to `auto`.

```
<p:dataTable ..... tableStyle="table-layout: auto;.....">......</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: With `auto` and `white-space: nowrap` the table overflow, so `auto` works well without it.

Comment: This makes the column-width dynamic as I wanted, but it does not prevent the table from overflowing, regardless of whether or not I set white-space: nowrap